# Tkinter entry cant be deleted when in function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im having difficulties with deleting content by a function when the entry was made by another function.

```
def recipe_add():
recepty_add_window = Toplevel()
recepty_add_window.geometry("400x400")

name_entry_label=Label(recepty_add_window, text="Name:").grid(row=1,column=0)
name_entry = Entry(recepty_add_window, width = 50, textvariable=name_var).grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5)

b_add = Button(recepty_add_window, text="Add recipe", width=50, command=add_recipe).grid(row=6, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx = 5)
```

The add_recipe has name_entry.delete function inside.

```
    def add_recipe():

name_entry.delete(0,END)
```

I receive: NameError: name 'name_entry' is not defined.

I tried to make name_entry global or changing the Toplevel to "single window app" by forgeting everythin that is a grid and putting it there again, nothing seems to help. Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a global variable where you define it, not where you use it. Also, `.grid()` returns `None`, so you first want to store the Entry in the variable and then call `grid()`:

```
from tkinter import *
def recipe_add():
    global name_entry
    name_var = StringVar()
    name_entry = Entry(recepty_add_window, width = 50, textvariable=name_var)
    name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5)

def add_recipe():
    name_entry.delete(0,END)
```